# What causes this "Incompatible operand types int and java.lang.String"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I get Incompatible operand types int and java.lang.String on my if line. I don't know what it is asking or how to fix it.

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
```

//Not sure wether the import above is needed or not
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
class Main{

     public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {

          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

           String ap = "April";
           String mar = "March";

      int one = 1;
      int two = 2;

      System.out.println("What month were you born in? (number)");
      int month = scan.nextInt();
      System.out.println("What day (number)");
      int day = scan.nextInt();
      if(((month == ap) && (day <= 19) || (month == mar) && (day >= 21))){
           System.out.println("Your birthday is: "+ month+ " "+day);
           System.out.println("Aries");
           System.out.println("Horoscope: ");
      }else
           System.out.println("HI"); //Just some filler code for compiling 



     }

}
```

Comment: How would a number `n` (like **1** or **2**) ever be a `String` like "April"?

Comment: You try to compare Strings and ints which is not possible.

Comment: What is your intention with the comparison of `month == mar` or equivalently: `5 == "March"` for example? This would never match even if it compiles. You should read the month as text (and compare with `equals`/`equalsIgnorecase`) or use the numbers for the months, not their English name in your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare `String` and `int` directly (you can get the `String` value of an `int` but I don't believe that would help you here), also the only import static that would make sense to me in your use case is `java.util.Calendar.*`. Then you need to subtract one from the input month, because Java considers [`Calendar.JANUARY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY) (the first month and what the [Static Import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) does) as month `0`. Finally, please display something meaningful instead of "HI" when your input isn't in the expected range. Something like

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.util.Calendar.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String str[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What month were you born in? (number)");
        int month = scan.nextInt() - 1;
        System.out.println("What day (number)");
        int day = scan.nextInt();
        if (((month == APRIL) && (day <= 19) || 
                (month == MARCH) && (day >= 21))) {
            System.out.println("Your birthday is: " + month + " " + day);
            System.out.println("Aries");
            System.out.println("Horoscope: ");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Month %d, Day %d%n", month, day);
        }
    }
}
```